# Copying an Image to the new instance in SixLabors.ImageSharp

Tags: c#, .net-4.8, imagesharp

The task is simple, however I can't figure it out. I have following function:

```
/// <summary>
/// Highlights areas on the image
/// </summary>
/// <param name="initialImage">Initial image to highlight on</param>
/// <param name="rectanglesToHighlight">Areas to highlight</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static Image Highlight(Image initialImage, params RectangleF[] rectanglesToHighlight)
{
      // Initial image
      Image result = initialImage.Clone(x => x.Opacity(1f));
      // Color of the mask
      Color maskColor = Color.Red;
      // Mask for each rectangle to highlight
      Image mask = new Image<Rgba32>(initialImage.Width, initialImage.Height, maskColor);
      // Recolor brush to draw transparent rectangles
      RecolorBrush brush = new RecolorBrush(maskColor, Color.Transparent, 1f);

      // Draw each rectangle on mask
      foreach(RectangleF rect in rectanglesToHighlight)
            // Draw current rectangle on mask with transparent color
            mask.Mutate(x => x.Clear(brush, rect));

      // Apply mask to the initial image
      result.Mutate(x => x.DrawImage(mask, PixelColorBlendingMode.Normal, 0.5f));

      // Return result image
      return result;
}
```

If I'm creating new variable like this:

```
Image result = initialImage;
```

Applying mask to **result** changes both **initialImage** and **result**.

I need to have variable with initial image in it, so the best way I found was to clone it with unnecessary function (in first line of code in the function).

My question is: How can I copy initial image into new instance without running unnecessary function? And I also wonder why **initialImage** changes at all.

Comment: `Image result = initialImage;` - You're assigning a reference to the initial image not creating a new image so any operation ran against result runs against the initial image.

Comment: @JamesSouth ok, I understand. How can I create a new instance with same image? I couldn't find any function for this. I want something like `Image result = initialImage.Copy();` or `Image result = new Image(initialImage);`

Comment: `Image.CloneAs<TPixel>` https://docs.sixlabors.com/api/ImageSharp/SixLabors.ImageSharp.Image.html#SixLabors_ImageSharp_Image_CloneAs__1

Comment: @JamesSouth thank you. Sorry for dumb question, couldn't find this method for some reason.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

`Image.ColoneAs<TPixel>`

[Documentation](https://docs.sixlabors.com/api/ImageSharp/SixLabors.ImageSharp.Image.html#SixLabors_ImageSharp_Image_CloneAs__1)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).